# Epsilon–delta proof of $\lim_{x\to\sqrt3}\frac1{x^2}=\frac13$

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

> Prove $\lim_{x\to\sqrt3}\frac1{x^2}=\frac13$ using the epsilon–delta definition.

Here is my work. Is it correct?
$$\left|\frac1{x^2}-\frac13\right|<\varepsilon\quad\quad|x-\sqrt3|<\delta$$
$$\left|\frac{(\sqrt3-x)(\sqrt3+x)}{3x^2}\right|<\varepsilon$$
$$\delta=1:|x-\sqrt3|<1$$
$$\sqrt3-1<x<\sqrt3+1$$
$$3(\sqrt3-1)^2<3x^2<3(\sqrt3+1)^2$$
$$\text{also: }2\sqrt3-1<x+\sqrt3<2\sqrt3+1$$
$$\therefore\left|\frac{(\sqrt3-x)(2\sqrt3+1)}{3(\sqrt3-1)^2}\right|<\varepsilon$$
$$|\sqrt3-x|<\frac{\varepsilon(3(\sqrt3-1)^2)}{2\sqrt3+1}$$
$$\therefore\frac{\varepsilon(3(\sqrt3-1)^2)}{2\sqrt3+1}=\delta$$
$$\left|\frac1{x^2}-\frac13\right|<\varepsilon$$

Comment: I think its better to do your work here itself, not to upload an image, may be this is why someone downvoted!

Comment: Thank , I am not used to MathJax I take my time read through the basic tutorial next time.